# Ruby on Rails Navigation Helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, navbar

I am coming from CakePHP where you can make a helper method, not related to any model or controller and simply import that method in a view. This is commonly used to define a menu, and import the menu at the top of all views so that a change to the menu is then global.

I can't find any resources on how to do this in Rails, all I see are form helpers in ERB and Navigation Gems which I am not interested in.

I already have my menu designed etc..., how do I implement it correctly (which I am assuming is the global helper, like in CakePHP).

I'm using Rails 4.0.0.

Comment: use the application helper . it will be available through out the application.

Answer (score 1):

Helper is meant to...help.

So, even you can write a helper to show nav, it's not good idea. This helper would be too heavy, and involves too much on view's business.

The better way is to use partial. Write a partial about nav, then render it in application layout.

Answer (score 0):

In Rails helpers are usually for *simple* [view related things](https://stackoverflow.com/a/399318/600953). If your nav is simple then a helper would be ok to use. But if it has any sort of logic in it then I'd recommend using a partial.